# postfix inet_interfaces

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server

I'm configuring postfix on CentOS. When I set

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

mail recieving works. But when I change it to

```
inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
```

mail is not recieved. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`myhostname` may be set incorrectly

It needs to resolve to the IP address that you need to listen on the internet with. i.e. most likely the primary IP of the machine as shown by `ip addr sh`

if you do a `host $(postconf myhostname)` where $myhostname is the value of `postconf myhostname` then you should see if it resolves correctly. The only exception to this is if the hostname is specified in /etc/hosts. So if the first doesn't resolve correctly, then try `grep $(postconf myhostname) /etc/hosts"

You may have multiple interfaces defined and myhostname is not the right interface to listen on.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of $myhostname? It might not contain a valid value.

Have a look at [this page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces).